# Guardar un modelo con múltiples relaciones con hijos agregados dinamicamente

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un problema al tratar de guardar un modelo con relaciones a las cuelas agregue dinámicamente hijos de la siguiente forma.

```
   $RatesPlansRoom = RatesPlansRooms::find(113);
    $calendarys = $RatesPlansRoom->calendarys()->whereBetween(
        'date',
        ["2019-08-29" ,"2019-09-10"]
    )->with([
        'rate'
    ])->get();
    $RatesPlansRoom->setRelation('calendarys', $calendarys);
    foreach ($this->getDateRange() as $dateInput) {
        $dateRates = $RatesPlansRoom->calendarys->first(function ($item) use ($date) {
            return $item->date == $date;
        });

        if (empty($dateRates)) { // create
            $dateRates = new RatesPlansCalendarys();
            $dateRates->date = $date;

            $RatesPlansRoom->calendarys->add($dateRates);
        }

        foreach ($rates as $rateType => $ratesType) {
            foreach ($ratesType as $rate) {
                $rateSelected = $dateRates->rate->first(function ($value) use ($rateType, $rate) {
                    return $value->num_adult == $rate['num_adult'];
                });

                if (empty($rateSelected)) {// create
                    $rateSelected = new Rates();
                    $rateSelected->fill($rate);

                    $dateRates->rate->add($rateSelected);

                } else {
                    $rateSelected->fill($rate);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $RatesPlansRoom->push();
```

Arroja el siguiente error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`limatours_copia_pruebas`.`rates`, CONSTRAINT
>   `rates_rates_plans_calendarys_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`rates_plans_calendarys_id`) REFERENCES `rates_plans_calendarys`
>   (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `rates` (`price_extra`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (70, 2019-08-29 21:24:00, 2019-08-29 21:24:00))

Al parecer es que en la relacion que se debe crear con

```
                $rateSelected = new Rates();
                $rateSelected->fill($rate);

                $dateRates->rate->add($rateSelected);
```

No esta llenando el campo "rates_plans_calendarys_id".

Comment: Qué es `add()`? No querrás usar [save()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method)?

Comment: En las lineas $RatesPlansRoom->calendarys->add($dateRates); y $dateRates->rate->add($rateSelected); se agregan hijos a la relacion dinamicamente sin guardarlos ya que ese proceso de guardado se a de hacer al invocar $RatesPlansRoom->push();